# Problem with Gimp: bad resolution

Tags: resolution, colors, gimp

I have some issues with Gimp. Something about the resolution. Sometimes you just can see the color change steps in gradients for instance. Something similar affects anti-aliasing.
Is this a bad installation problem, a Gimp limitation, a system configuration issue, or...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because GIMP can handle only 8bit per color channel. That makes 254 gradations *between* pure white and pure black. That is, if you draw a gradient from white to black further than 256 pixels you will already get staircase. Same if you draw a gradient from mid-grey to black or white further than 128 px.

Answer (score 1):

I was new to Ubuntu 2 years ago, and also to Gimp. I still have much to learn about Ubuntu and Gimp. I do a lot of picture editing, resizing, compressing for websites, color adjusting, etc., and I have fallen in love with Gimp. What helped me a great deal was the Gimp Lite tutorial on their site.

Now to your problem. This is just a guess, but I think it may be a lack of sufficient memory, or video memory on your system. Those are the only times I've seen what you are describing show up. I've never had any issues with Gimp not working at all. Maybe some folks can give you an analytical way to know if this is the issue.

If you know the following information, please post it for me to review:
1. Processor - Make, Model, Cores
2. RAM on your computer
3. Video Ram on your video
4. What size pictures are you working with? If they are very large from newer high mega pixel cameras, have you tried to resize them to see if you still have the issues when you work on them?
5. Are you using Gimp with a lot of other programs open?